# updating a record mysql with zend framework 2

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

I want to update a record, in my case the records name is kindOfFood_vote

I don't quite understand yet how to update a specific record. 
I did it this way, but it doesn't work so I assume it's wrong.

first a made a variable data where i store it :

```
 $data = array(
            'kindOfFood_name' => $food->kindOfFood_name,
            'kindOfFood_votes' => $food->kindOfFood_votes += 1,
 );
```

The insert query works fine, But maybe there can be something wrong with this line of code : 
'kindOfFood_votes' => $food->kindOfFood_votes += 1,

This is were I insert or update :

```
if ($id == 0) {
            if ($rowset->count() > 0) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data,array('kindOfFood_name' => $kindOfFood_name));
            }else{
                $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            }

        }
```

I don't see the problem.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
$data = array(
        'kindOfFood_name' => $food->kindOfFood_name,
        'kindOfFood_votes' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('kindOfFood_votes + 1'),
);
```

For single record this would have worked -

```
$this->tableGateway->update(
    array(
        'kindOfFood_votes' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('kindOfFood_votes + 1')
    ),     
    array('kindOfFood_name' => $kindOfFood_name)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I have the problem that i can only update 2 times and then it stops working. I don't know if that has something to do with the code or with my database. But again thank you!